# After boot I have two instances of Pure Data application

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, lxsession, puredata

Raspbian Jessie on Pi 3 headless with VNC on laptop. I use /LXEsession/autostart to have application `puredata` running after boot.
In Terminal with `top` 2 instances of `puredata` show up!!

How come?

Anybody an idea about this?

```
pi@murf:~ $ ps aux | grep puredata  
pi        1120  1.4  0.6  12632  6056 ?        S    13:52   0:01 puredata  
pi        1121  1.4  0.6  12632  5916 ?        S    13:52   0:01 puredata  
pi        1149  0.0  0.0   1912   372 ?        S    13:52   0:00 sh -c TCL_LIBRARY="/usr/lib/puredata/lib/tcl/library" TK_LIBRARY="/usr/lib/puredata/lib/tk/library"   wish "/usr/lib/puredata/tcl//pd-gui.tcl" 5400   
pi        1150  0.0  0.0   1912   364 ?        S    13:52   0:00 sh -c /usr/lib/puredata/bin/pd-watchdog  
pi        1151  0.7  1.3  26416 12676 ?        Sl   13:52   0:01 wish /usr/lib/puredata/tcl//pd-gui.tcl 5400  
pi        1152  0.0  0.0   1840   424 ?        S    13:52   0:00 /usr/lib/puredata/bin/pd-watchdog  
pi        1153  0.0  0.0   1912   364 ?        S    13:52   0:00 sh -c TCL_LIBRARY="/usr/lib/puredata/lib/tcl/library" TK_LIBRARY="/usr/lib/puredata/lib/tk/library"   wish "/usr/lib/puredata/tcl//pd-gui.tcl" 5401   
pi        1154  0.0  0.0   1912   388 ?        S    13:52   0:00 sh -c /usr/lib/puredata/bin/pd-watchdog  
pi        1155  0.0  0.0   1840   380 ?        S    13:52   0:00 /usr/lib/puredata/bin/pd-watchdog  
pi        1156  0.6  1.3  26536 12748 ?        Sl   13:52   0:00 wish /usr/lib/puredata/tcl//pd-gui.tcl 5401  
pi        1420  0.0  0.2   4280  2016 pts/0    S+   13:54   0:00 grep --color=auto puredata
```

---

```
pi@murf:~ $ ps -o pid,ppid,cmd -p 1087 1088
  PID  PPID CMD
 1087   962 puredata
 1088   913 puredata
pi@murf:~ $ pstree -p 962
lxsession(962)─┬─lxpanel(1083)─┬─{gdbus}(1126)
               │               ├─{gmain}(1129)
               │               └─{menu-cache-io}(1244)
               ├─lxpolkit(1080)───{gdbus}(1092)
               ├─openbox(1075)
               ├─pcmanfm(1086)─┬─{gdbus}(1127)
               │               └─{gmain}(1131)
               ├─puredata(1087)─┬─sh(1116)───wish(1119)───{wish}(1133)
               │                └─sh(1117)───pd-watchdog(1118)
               ├─ssh-agent(987)
               ├─{gdbus}(1028)
               └─{gmain}(1065)
pi@murf:~ $ pstree -p 913
lxsession(913)─┬─lxpanel(1084)─┬─{gdbus}(1128)
               │               ├─{gmain}(1135)
               │               └─{menu-cache-io}(1242)
               ├─lxpolkit(1079)───{gdbus}(1091)
               ├─openbox(1074)
               ├─pcmanfm(1085)─┬─{gdbus}(1132)
               │               └─{gmain}(1142)
               ├─puredata(1088)─┬─sh(1120)───wish(1124)───{wish}(1134)
               │                └─sh(1121)───pd-watchdog(1123)
               ├─ssh-agent(953)
               ├─{gdbus}(1025)
               └─{gmain}(1066)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the output of `ps aux | grep puredata`.

Comment: The parent process ID would be useful here too unless an actual puredata user comes along to clarify whether this is normal (it certainly isn't unusual for a background application to fork into multiple processes).   Add the output from `ps -o pid,ppid,cmd -p 1120 1121`.  I'll bet the second column is 1 (or something corresponding to the lxde) and 1120.

Comment: @goldilocks  PID  PPID CMD  
 1097  1008 puredata  
 1098   919 puredata

Comment: Well, I'm at least partially wrong.  You could check `pstree -p 1008` and `pstree -p 919` to see what started them and if there is any overlap in the trees (although that output seems a bit odd if you asked for 1120 and 1121 yet neither of them are mentioned -- but presumably you didn't do that and used the actual current pids).  If you haven't used `pstree` before the man page and just plain `pstree` should clarify what that is about.

Comment: @goldilocks : i have a picture of pstree -p ....

Comment: @goldilocks : sorry, hit return. i don't know how to include a picture

Comment: There's a little mountain icon in the edit interface (`edit` below the question) for uploading images.  However, if you can cut n' paste the output instead, then highlight it all and use the code formatter (the `{ }` icon), it should appear correctly.

Comment: Sorry to have forgotten about you for a while.  I'm not an LXDE user, but it seems odd to me there's two identical process trees there.  I'd say either you're logged in twice, or it has to do with VNC (which I also don't use), or both (as in, you logged in remotely, got disconnected, but weren't logged out, then logged in again).

Comment: @goldilocks : from a puredata forum somebody gave me this [link] (https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=59285).

Comment: So if you are using tightvnc that is the culprit -- that's kinda crappy but probably not a big deal; that stuff will use a lot of *shared* memory, although it will waste a not-insignificant-on-the-pi amount (of non-shared).  It won't waste any processor time though since no one is actually using it.  You could try killing the first one to see what happens...  Anyway, please leave that as an answer here if you have time.

Answer (score 1):

Using X11VNC there's indeed no second instance of my app.
Another solution seems to be: booting the headless Pi in CLI mode. Then with Tightvncserver there's not a second instance of my app either.

With the little experience i have, i prefer Tightvncserver because with X11VNC the connection too often got unresponsive, making a reboot necessary.

thanks for the assistance
rolf

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.